# What was Lord Refa's accent?

Tags: babylon-5, accent

One of the nicer touches to JMS's worldbuilding of the *Babylon 5* universe is the fact that many of the alien species, and even different characters within the same species, speak with different accents (unlike in a lot of English-language sci-fi where pretty much everyone has a British or American accent no matter which galaxy they're from). We've got Delenn with her Croatian-influenced accent, [Londo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/167717/31394) with his part-Czech, part-Irish accent, but not all Centauri speak in the same way, as you can see in this scene:

Lord Refa always reminded me slightly of an Italian mafioso, but I'm not sure if that's an accurate description of his accent. **What accent is William Forward (the actor) using for Lord Refa?**

Comment: "*Actually, Lord Refa has an accent almost identical to Londo's, and
Emperor Turhan had quite an accent as well, so we'e done a lot of this
already (also Londo's friend in Knives).*" - [JMS](http://www.jmsnews.com/Messages/Message/15405)

Comment: "*No, we've just always assumed that not everyone on any given
planet is going to speak with the same accent as everybody else from
that planet. Seems more realistic. Certainly, among Centauri, a certain accent is more associated with the "old school" of court nobility and the like."* - [JMS](http://www.jmsnews.com/messages/message?id=13042)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Bill Forward was just copying Peter Jurasik's fake accent.

Comment: Maybe even elaborating on it a bit.

Comment: I'm fairly sure there's a line in the Centauri trilogy novels or maybe the novelization of B5: In the Beginning that mentions Londo's accent is looked down on by the high Court snobs as it is from a distant region relative to the Palace.  But that's a 20 year old memory.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Babylon 5 Fandom page](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Antono_Refa):

> Refa's accent (and by extension Londo Mollari's, and Urza Jaddo's) is characteristic of Centauri Prime's northern province and is generally indicative of the "old school" of court nobility.<sup>[1]</sup> <sup>[[2]](http://www.jmsnews.com/Messages/Message/4913)</sup>
>
> <sup>[1]</sup> The Long Night of Centauri Prime - (p.117)
> <sup>[2]</sup> [JMS post on CIS - 4/21/1996 5:09:00 PM](http://www.jmsnews.com/msg.aspx?id=1-4913)

So the accent being different isn't necessarily intentional, or based on any real-world accents, it's just how the actor portrayed the character.  It should be similar to [Londo's](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/167718/141465).

Comment: What's the original source for this claim? Fandom/Wikia sites are generally unreliable sources since anyone can edit random stuff into them.

Comment: @Randal'Thor They had sources on their page, I've included them in my answer now.